# How to highlight trails on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-labels

If I zoom in really far on Google Maps it'll show trails (like rail to trail: Virginia Creeper)

But if I zoom back out it disappears. I've looked in the menu at Layers and have read that Layers included a TRAILS options. But I don't see it.

How can I highlight a Trail on Google maps?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
Menu > Layers >bike

[image]